# Openshift disk quota full by adding JAR files

Tags: java, maven, jar, openshift

I am having a problem with the disk quota limit on open shift. Whenever, I add an external jar, which is small (6.7 MB) in size, by adding it to the Maven Dependencies (through pom.xml), the disk size increases a bit. But that is usual. The current disk usage is 397 MB. But when I add my final jar file which is about 350 MB in size, the disk usage goes to 1 GB, meaning that it is completely full. But I only added a about of 750 MB. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sshing into your gear and using the "du -hc" command to see what is taking up so much disk space.  Since you are putting the jar files into the git repository, it takes up double the space, 350MB in the git repository, and then 350MB in the directory where it is deployed.  Also, if you made changes to the jar file and uploaded a new copy, since it is an archive it will be versioned in git as a large file and take up even more space.

Comment: Ok I see. There is no way to have it just in one place, instead of the two. I saw as you were saying that the JAR file is in the git repository and another maven one. Is there a way to just put it in the git repository, so it doesn't take double the space?